# Installing my program on Windows CE 5

Tags: c#, installation, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm in the progress of finishing up an application for Windows CE 5, and I was wondering what the easiest way of installing the application on CE 5 devices would be.

Hitting "publish" in VS8 generates an installer, but this installer isn't compatible with CE 5.

**What is an easy, effective way of installing my applications on Windows CE 5?**

Edit: Follow-up **[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188630/smartdevice-cab-is-not-a-valid-windows-ce-setup-file)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to just add a new Deployment project to your existing solution.

Right-Click your solution and pick Add > New Project

[image: add new project]

Go to Other Project Types, select the **Smart Device CAB Project**

[image: Cab Project]

Right click the new project, including all the files your project uses, then **build it**.

**UPDATE:**

Be sure to Add Project Output!

[image: project output]

Comment: this setup for desktop application not for smart device applications

Comment: Whoops. Good catch. Select the **Smart Device CAB Project**. Answer has been updated!

Comment: This worked great! I never even looked at the setup & development projects. I assume I can use the "Setup Project" project for regular desktop applications?

Comment: When running the built CAB on my CE 5 device, I seem to be getting the error "The file {0} is not a valid Windows CE Setup file." where {0} is the path to the file. Any help?

Comment: Be sure to Add Project Output. See Update.

Comment: @jp2code, I did do that, that's what's so weird about the errors. I've made a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188630/smartdevice-cab-is-not-a-valid-windows-ce-setup-file) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

For windows CE and windows mobile applications use CAB file, in [this link](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html) describe how to create CAB file.